# Applescript for Excel: How to format range as date and 1900 date system

Tags: excel, date, format, applescript

I have a script I have written that is mostly successful in it's goal to create SQL statements from a CSV file. The 2 hitches I have right now are 1) the date column in the csv file is formatted as "General" and so appearing as a number instead of a date, and 2) when converted to date it is using the 1904 date system, and is, of course showing the year as 4 years into the future (2015 is appearing as 2019). I have scoured the web and Excel 2004 Applescript Guide.

Here are the commands I currently have which at least compile and run without error, but also do not accomplish what I'm hoping to do:

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        try
            close workbooks saving no
        end try
        open working_file
        set date type of active workbook to date 1900
        tell active workbook

            tell active sheet
                set datecolumn to range ("A2:A100" as string)
                select datecolumn
                set data type of datecolumn to date data 
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
```

Comment: Sorry, no Mac to test this on. Is it possible to put 4 years of days onto the clipboard and `.PasteSpecial Operation:=xlSubtract`. Another option would be temporarily swapping the workbook's date format with something akin to `ActiveWorkbook.Date1904 = False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script bellow unset the preference flag date 1904 and also format the range to date format dd/mm/yyyy. you can also adjust it to other format like US format if needed (mm/dd/yy) :

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
front document activate
set date 1904 of active workbook to false
set datecolumn to range "A2:A100" of active sheet of active workbook
set number format of datecolumn to "dd/mm/yyyy"
end tell
```